# C++: Function pointer as Template argument instead of functor

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, functor

I have been trying to create this class which can either use the default functor as an argument or the user can provide one if he wants. But I am unable to pass function pointer as my template argument. Can you please help me in understanding what I am missing.

```
template <typename T>
struct CheckFunctor
{
    bool operator()(T obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
};



template <typename _Ty,
class _Pr = CheckFunctor<_Ty>
>
class MyClass
{
    typedef _Ty                     mapped_type;
    typedef _Pr                     CanBeCleaned_type;

    _Ty data;
    CanBeCleaned_type predicate;

public:  

    void SomeMethod()
    {
            if( predicate(data))
            {
              std::cout << "Do something";
            }
    }
       MyClass(_Ty timeOutDuration, _Pr pred = _Pr())
        : data( timeOutDuration), predicate( pred)
    {}   
};

template< typename T>
struct CheckEvenFunctor
{
   bool operator()(T val)
    {
       return (val%2 == 0);
    }
};


bool CheckEven( int val)
{
    return (val%2 == 0);
}

int main()
{
//Usage -1
    MyClass<int> obj1( 5);

//Usage- 2
 MyClass< int, CheckEven> obj2(6, CheckEven);  //Error: 'CheckEven' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Pr'

 //Usage -3 
 MyClass<int, CheckEvenFunctor<int>>( 7);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use an object (`CheckEven`) as a type (`class _Pr`)

Comment: Can I do something with my MyCLass so that it accepts both functionPtr and Functors. I want to keep the usage of MyClass simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass `CheckEven` as a type parameter even though `CheckEven` is not a type but a function (of type `bool(int)`). You should define the type as a pointer to the type of function that you are passing. `decltype` is handy here:

```
MyClass< int, decltype(&CheckEven)> obj2(6, CheckEven);
```

You can also create a factory function and let the compiler deduce the template parameters:

```
template<class T, class F>
MyClass<T, F> makeClass(T timeOutDuration, F pred) {
    return {timeOutDuration, pred};
}

auto obj2 = makeClass(6, CheckEven);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to allow a template parameter to be a function, but your `MyClass` is expecting the second argument to be a type, not a function. You might think that template specialization could be used to allow you to define `MyClass` to also take a function in the second template argument, but it won't work. Template specialization allows you to modify the behavior of `MyClass` for particular types that are passed as template arguments, but those types must still match the template definition of `MyClass`, which is that the two arguments are types.

You could modify the type of `MyClass` you are instantiating by making the second argument a function pointer type as suggested in a different answer, but you would lose the advantage of template expansion making your calls to functions inline. Another solution would be to create a helper class that will convert your function into a functor, and use that to create your `MyClass` instance.

```
template <bool P (int)>
struct F {
    bool operator()(int obj) { return P(obj); }
};

//...
MyClass<int, F<CheckEven> > obj2(6);
```